Create Dynmic models in DBT + Bigquery
I have a table fedex_2_charges and would like to create child tables based on a column client, where each unique client results in a separate table like fedex_2_charges_client_1,
fedex_2_charges_client_2 etc
my attempt so far is as follows.
Environment
Running with dbt=1.7.11
Registered adapter: bigquery=1.7.7
{% set unique_clients_query %}
select distinct array_reverse(split(_file_name,'/'))[offset(1)] client from data.fedex_2
order by 1
{% endset %}
{% set unique_clients = run_query(unique_clients_query) %}
{% for client_name in unique_clients.columns[0].values() %}
{% set client_model_name = "fedex_2_charges_" + client_name %}
{% set query %}
SELECT *
FROM {{ ref('fedex_2_charges') }}
WHERE client = '{{ client_name }}'
{% endset %}

{{ config(
  materialized='table',
  tags=['fedex_2', 'core'],
  unique_id=client,
  alias='fedex_2_charges_' ~ client_name
) }}

{{ query }}
{% endfor %}

this results in a compilation error
Compilation Error in model fedex_2_client_charges (models\fedex_2\fedex_2_client_charges.sql)
  'None' has no attribute 'table'. This can happen when calling a macro that does not exist. Check for typos and/or install package dependencies with "dbt deps".

My hypothesis is that DBT is trying to compile this code but is able to do so since it doesn't have the results of the query select distinct array_reverse(split(_file_name,'/'))[offset(1)] client from data.fedex_2 since its compiling.
I am not sure how to fix this, I read on DBT forums I need to encapsulate this block in an if execute macro but on doing that the model is just skipped.
{% set unique_clients_query %}
select distinct array_reverse(split(_file_name,'/'))[offset(1)] client from data.fedex_2
order by 1
{% endset %}
{% set unique_clients = run_query(unique_clients_query) %}
{% if execute %}
{% for client_name in unique_clients.columns[0].values() %}
{% set client_model_name = "fedex_2_charges_" + client_name %}
{% set query %}
SELECT *
FROM {{ ref('fedex_2_charges') }}
WHERE client = '{{ client_name }}'
{% endset %}

{{ config(
  materialized='table',
  tags=['fedex_2', 'core'],
  unique_id=client,
  alias='fedex_2_charges_' ~ client_name
) }}

{{ query }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}


Im not sure but I think the issue comes from the config.
You are basically creating a script that is supposed to generate N tables, but instead, you are trying to build it as a separate dbt model for each table.
I am not aware of dbt capabilities that support that, but I could be wrong.
I think a different approach can be having a manually crafted script, i.e. instead of select * and specifying the config, just go ahead and run "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE..."

It's beyond the scope of an answer, but I encourage you to consider whether it's a good idea to do this. I haven't been in your shoes, so maybe it is. However, my 'doctrine' is that with DBT you don't want schema changes to happen 'automagically'; you want to capture them in version control. For that reason I would avoid using SELECT * and generating tables based on what data values are stored in your tables.

@PaddyAlton I have 600 clients in the table, the reason we want to split the data is on testing it was found that the cost of the queries did not change with a single well clustered table vs individual tables, there was a 12% improving in speed by using smaller tables.
Currently we are achieving this by having a python cloud function run the 600 odd queries in batches of 50 taking about 8-10 mins per bacth. it was suggested that dbt can achieve this hence we gave it a shot.
in essence this scrip was supposed to create multiple models on runtime. but i don't think its possible

I see - a performance-critical use case. I am surprised clustering on client doesn't help; are your downstream queries filtering on WHERE client = 'client name' AND ...? The clustering column must be first in the WHERE clause IIRC (or at least, first after any partitioning column you are using).

@PaddyAlton that is correct,
we use select * from where client = xxx as the first CTE and then do all analytics on this cte
but there are 2 reasons why client specific tables are necessary

BI tool misbehave they dont always filter by client first|
the team of analyst are human and sometime idiots and do select * without a filter. each unfiltered select * query costs us ~100$. So the reason is to deal with real world idiosyncrasies more than anything else.


Fair enough. I think this is a poor use case for DBT: ultimately it is just Python code executing SQL queries, which you already have. It excels when you're applying version control to your outcomes, less so in these circumstances. In your case you may like to push more of your logic into BigQuery (I wrote this answer recently, so it's top of mine).
